# How to prevent Gunicorn from honoring client-initiated renegotions?

Tags: python, security, ssl, gunicorn

I downloaded the SSL vulnerability tester [SSlyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze) and ran it against my gunicorn port. One of the results was:

```
* Session Renegotiation:
  Client-initiated Renegotiations:   VULNERABLE - Server honors client-initiated renegotiations
```

Is there a Gunicorn setting I can use to prevent it from honoring client initiated renegotiations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Gunicorn as a web server.  Proxy it with Nginx.  Nginx is good at being a web server, Gunicorn is good at being a WSGI server.  [Nginx disabled renegotiation in 2009](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES).